# Facebook Graph APi 6.0 - Is there a way to get latest facebook pages post without manage_pages permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I want to get my x latests posts from my FB page to embed them on my website, all that i found need manage_pages permission, but i just want to read, no create, no update.
Does someone find a way to do it?
PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You are _supposed to_ use `manage_pages` in a situation like that. The only possible alternative would be to submit your app for approval of the [Page Public Content Access feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS)  - but it is doubtful Facebook would approve that, if the stated purpose of you app is to only show your own page’s posts, and also whether that would even fall under the allowed use cases for that feature.

Comment: (For a fully public page, you could also just use the Page Plugin, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/ - that allows you to show the page timeline, but you’d be limited to the few layout options Facebook offers.)

Comment: Okay, thank for the answer!

Comment: And what if i let my app in dev mode, i can use manage_pages without the permission, and i need it only for one account. I know it's not recommended but is that a problem ?

Comment: Just for reading, that should probably work. (Anything you’d try and publish, would only be visible to users with a role in the app.) And the rate limits are lower in dev mode, I think - so you should cache the data on your end, and not make a request on every page load or something.